# How do I give a service running as SYSTEM shared directory network access over EC2 hosts running Windows Server 2012?

Tags: amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, teamcity, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-networking

The scenario is as follows:

I have TeamCity set up to use AWS EC2 hosts running Windows Server 2012 R2 as build agents. In this configuration, the TeamCity agent service is running as SYSTEM. I am trying to implement FastBuild as our new compilation process. In order to use the distributed compilation functionality of FastBuild, the build agent host needs to have access to a shared network folder. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to give this kind of access from one machine to another.

To help further the explanation, I'll use named examples. The networked folder, C:\Shared-Folder, lives on a host named Central-Host. The build agent lives on Builder-Host. Everything is running Windows Server 2012 R2 on EC2 hosts that are fully network permissive to each other via AWS security groups. What I need is to share a directory from Central-Host so that Builder-Host can fully access it via a directory structure like this:

```
\\Central-Host\Shared-Folder
```

By RDPing into both hosts using the default Administrator account, I can very easily set up the network sharing and browse (while on Builder-Host) to the \\Central-Host\Shared-Folder location. I can also open up the command line and run:

```
type NUL > \\Central-Host\Shared-Folder\Empty.txt
```

with the result of an empty text file being created at that networked location.

**The problem arises from the SYSTEM account.** When I grab PSTOOLS and use the command:

```
PSEXEC -i -s cmd.exe
```

I can test commands that will be given by TeamCity. Again, it is a service being run as SYSTEM which, I need to emphasize, *cannot be changed to a normal User* due to other issues we have when using TeamCity agents under the User account type.

After much searching I have discovered how to set up Active Directory services so that I can add Users and Computers from the domain but after doing so, I still face access denied errors. I am probably missing something important and I hope someone here can help. I believe this problem will be considered "solved" when I can successfully run the "type NUL" command shown above.

Comment: Have you tried granting 'ANONYMOUS LOGON', or 'Everyone' rights to the \\Central-Host\Shared-Folder share?

Comment: @SteveChapman I have, it still provides an access denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer for the permissions issue, but rather a way to avoid it. (Wanted to add this as a comment, but StackOverflow won't let me - weird.)

The shared network drive is used only for the remote worker discovery. If you have a fixed list of workers, instead of using the worker discovery, you can specify them explicitly in your config file as follows:

```
Settings
{
    .Workers =
    {
        'hostname1'     // specify hostname
        'hostname2'
        '192.168.0.10' // or ip
    }

    ... // the other stuff that goes here
```

This functionality is not documented, as to-date all users have wanted the automatic worker discovery. It is fine to use however, and if it is indeed useful, it can be elevated to a supported feature with just a documentation update.

Comment: .Workers has been added to the documentation and will be considered as an officially supported feature from the next release (v0.87)